# how to use mavlink_msg_message_interval_encode?

Tags: c++, mavlink

I'm trying to set a msg interval in ardupilot using mavlink.
I know about msg MESSAGE_INTERVAL(#244), that may be send to the Pixhawk and I'm trying to do it by mavlink_msg_message_interval_encode(systemId, componentId, message, interval).
But I have no idea what is the right values for systemId and componentId.

(In general, I just want to receive msg SCALED_IMU (#26) )

My code

```
mavlink_message_t message;
mavlink_message_interval_t interval;
interval.message_id = 36;
interval.interval_us = 10000; 
mavlink_msg_message_interval_encode(255, 0, &message, &interval);
```

I've read, that systemId classic val is 255, and set componentId as 0 just because.

It didn't work out to adjust the frequency with such argument values.
I also tried a crazy idea to do a double loop on (0...500)x (0...300) and sort through all the pairs, but it didn't end with success either...

Answer (score 0):

I've managed!
The problem: MESSAGE_INTERVAL is "the interval between messages for a particular MAVLink message ID. This message is sent in response to the MAV_CMD_REQUEST_MESSAGE command" (https://mavlink.io/en/messages/common.html#MESSAGE_INTERVAL)

To set the mgs frequency, you should send a COMMAND_LONG msg with "command: 511 (for MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL)" (https://ardupilot.org/dev/docs/mavlink-requesting-data.html)

It works, as I see

(my working code)

```
mavlink_message_t message;
mavlink_command_long_t command_long;
command_long.target_system = 1;
command_long.target_component = 0;
command_long.confirmation = 0;
command_long.command = MAV_CMD_SET_MESSAGE_INTERVAL;
command_long.param1 = msg_id;
command_long.param2 = frequency;
command_long.param3 = 0;
command_long.param4 = 0;
command_long.param5 = 0;
command_long.param6 = 0;
command_long.param7 = 0;
mavlink_msg_command_long_encode_chan(systemId,
                                     componentId,
                                     MAVLINK_COMM_3, // place your comm
                                     &message, &command_long);
communicator.sendMessage(message);
```